# how do I remove all cameraAction

Tags: animation, camera

I have a 3D object with some animation on it. And a camera with some animation on it. I want to export only the 3D object with the animtion to FBX. So I remove the keyframes of the camera, I remove the camera I, deselect camera in the FBX export settings.
When I import in Unity3D i still see 'cameraAction' in the FBX properties (see image).
How can I remove all cameraAction in blender?

[image: FBX animation properties Unity3D]

Comment: remove this action then save and reopen  the file to take effect , in blender on action could be shared between objects so make sure the action has zero users to be removed, in case you have many actions I can provide a script

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove an action from an object by going to the 'Dopesheet':

[image]

Switch to the 'Action Editor' in the Dopesheet header and press the 'x' next to the action name (CameraAction in this case):

[image]

This will remove the action from the object selected in the 3D view.

If the action is not used by any other objects it will be removed from the file when the file is saved, closed and re-opened.